# flexbox item 100% of remaining width

Tags: css, flexbox, width

I want to achieve the following scenario with flexbox

[image]

the green element is a text element and the width is flexible. The blue elements should have 100% of the remaining width beside the green element.

My current solution looks like this:

```
<div class="container">
  <span class="title">title</span>
  <div class="fullwidth"></div>
  <div class="fullwidth"></div>
  <div class="fullwidth"></div>
</div>
```

and the css:

```
.container {
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  background-color: #EAEBEF;

  .title {
    padding: 20px;
    background-color: #48CFAE;
  }

  .fullwidth {
    background-color: #87BDFF;
    flex: 0 0 100%;
    height: 60px;
    margin: 10px 0;
  }
}
```

But it looks currently like this
[image: current state]
here is a [codepen example](https://codepen.io/iamrbn/pen/vrxxjM)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Without changing the HTML this can be managed with CSS-Grid as an *alternative* to flexbox.

```css
.container {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: max-content 1fr;
  grid-gap: 1em;
  background-color: #EAEBEF;
  margin-bottom: 1em;
}

.title {
  padding: 10px;
  grid-row: 2;
  background-color: #48CFAE;
}

.fullwidth {
  grid-column: 2;
  background-color: #87BDFF;
  height: 40px;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="title">title</div>
  <div class="fullwidth"></div>
  <div class="fullwidth"></div>
  <div class="fullwidth"></div>
</div>

<div class="container">
  <div class="title">Longer title</div>
  <div class="fullwidth"></div>
  <div class="fullwidth"></div>
  <div class="fullwidth"></div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this HTML and CSS markup. Basically You need to keep the left side in one div and the right side elements in another div.

```css
 
   .container {
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  flex-wrap: nowrap;
  background-color: #eaebef;
}
.container .title {
  padding: 20px;
  background-color: #48cfae;
}
.container .div1 {
  width: 20%;
}
.container .div2 {
  width: 80%;
}
.container .fullwidth {
  background-color: #87bdff;
  height: 60px;
  margin: 10px 0;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
<div class="div1">
 <span class="title">title</span>
</div>
<div class="div2">
 <div class="fullwidth"></div>
 <div class="fullwidth"></div>
 <div class="fullwidth"></div>
</div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

**See code below:**

You have to warp `fullwidth` in `div` and set `width` to this `div`
also set `width` and `margin` to `title`

```css
.container {
 display: flex;
 align-items: center;
 flex-wrap: wrap;
 background-color: #EAEBEF;
} 
 .title {
  width: 20%;
  padding: 20px;
  background-color: #48CFAE;
        margin-left: 15px;

 }
 
 .fullwidth {
  background-color: #87BDFF;
  flex: 0 0 100%;
  height: 60px;
  margin: 10px 0;
 }
 .a{
      margin: 50px;
      width: 50%;
 }
```

```html
<div class="container">
 <span class="title">title</span>
 <div class="a">
 <div class="fullwidth"></div>
 <div class="fullwidth"></div>
 <div class="fullwidth"></div>
 </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score -1):

If you want to achive this without change your html but only your less, try this:

```
.container {
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: row;
    align-items: center;
    flex-wrap: wrap;
    background-color: #EAEBEF;
    justify-content: flex-end;
    .title {
          padding: 20px;
          background-color: #48CFAE;
          margin-right: 20px;
          flex-grow: 1
    }
    .fullwidth {
          background-color: #87BDFF;
          height: 60px;
          margin: 10px 0;
          width: 80%;
    }
}
```

[your codepen edited](https://codepen.io/anon/pen/wXJeXR)

Comment: Sorry i've not seen seen your image. If you need to center vertically the first div you can't do without change first your html structure. The other's answers are better than mine.